# what is the best approach to listen and process messages concurrently in kafka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

I am working on a *Kafka application* to process requests from `topic-request-A` and call microservice and publish the response to `topic-response-A`.

I have 100 microservices to be called, so I have 100 topics for the request
`(topic-request-A1,topic-request-A2 .... topic-request-A100)` and 100 topics for response `(topic-response-A1,topic-response-A2 .... topic-response-A100)`.

I am using spring *@KafkaListener* annotation to listen to the 100 request topics, this way is treating as a sequential process instead of a parallel process.

How I can listen to the request parallel way?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Is there a reason each microservice doesn't just subscribe to the `topic-request-A` directly? and produce directly back to `topic-response-A`? Each microservice can then consume & produce in parallel.

Comment: It is not possible because each topic has separate avro schema.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the number of partitions on each topic, then set the concurrency on the `@KafkaListener`; the number of partitions must be greater than, or equal to, the concurrency.

Comment: Thanks Gary, how many partitions you suggest me to have in production environment if I have 100 topics?

Comment: It depends on whatever concurrency you want to achieve on each topic. Partitions must be >= concurrency; it's generally better to over-provision partitions so you can easill increase concurrency later.

Comment: Thank you Gary. If I have 5 different methods for listening 5 different topics with concurrency 3 and partition size 3, I can achieve 5*3 times faster performance. isn't it ?

Comment: Theoretically, yes; practically something less than that - it depends on what your application is doing with the records, CPU availability, I/O bandwidth, etc, etc.

Comment: That is fine Gary, I wanted to set up listener with like this 
   public  void listen(List<ConsumerRecord<String, Req>> payloads, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {}

I got following error 
A 'RetryTemplate' is not supported with a batch listener; consider configuring the container with a suitably configured 'SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler' instead

could you help me how to resolve that ?

Comment: Retries at the listener level are not supported with batch listeners. Now that most container error handlers support retry, back off, exception classification, you should use one the batch error handlers. The best one is the `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling

Comment: Thanks Gary. Now it is working without any error. 
why payloads's size is 1?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean; I suggest you ask a new question showing your code and configuration.